# iOS VewController with a manual handler on top to slide up/down

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

What is it called a type of ViewController that has a **little manual handler** on the top (see screenshot below) that if you drag it you pull the viewController up from the bottom or down to a complete dismiss?

Searched for hours. No documentation with similar images anywhere.

[image]

Can someone please lead me in the right direction? How is that handler called? Is it even a view controller or a part of bottom navigation???

Thanks

Comment: It has no formal name and it is not a built in object. I call it a “grabber”.

Comment: Are you saying that this little thin on Maps (made by apple), Music (made by Apple) and many other apple made products and it has no build-in object?????

Comment: Correct. You will need to make your own or find a library

Comment: Well... apart from that grabber ... the way how the view controller stick out from the bottom and then pulled up manually - what's the approach? Is it something to do withUIPresentationController?

Comment: you will be in need to do some transitions

Comment: But is it a view controller? Does it have a specific name (maybe)? It has those round top corners.

Comment: I will say it like draggable dismiss :D

Answer (score 0):

Its Interactive dismiss viewController **though its not a formal name but most of searches shows this name**

Below URL will help you to send you in right direction, you are just in need to use it according to your need.

https://www.thorntech.com/2016/02/ios-tutorial-close-modal-dragging/